# How to show multiple images in one div which have same date

Tags: php, mysqli

When Multiple images are uploaded at a time..
I want to access all those images which are of same date..

```
$aa  = "SELECT imgdate  FROM db WHERE pid=1";

foreach ($aa as $value) {

 $dd ="SELECT images FROM db WHERE imgdate=$value";

}
```

All the images must be shown with same date..

thanks..

Comment: Please show us example code. What have you tried already? This is to less information to help you.

Comment: this is what i have tried..

Comment: What happens when you run that query? You have not provide all of the code you are using. What you posted simply put the contents of the query into a variable.

Comment: Hi, I would recommend that you read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly. In it's current state, it's impossible for anyone to give you a proper answer since we have no idea what the expected result should look like, what you've tried (more than a single query) and what result you're currently getting.

Comment: only thing I see that could be wrong in your sql, is that the db name would need ` db` to make sure its the correct one it gets, else your sql is correct

Comment: i gets results in array..

Comment: of course if there is more than one with that pid

Answer (score 1):

To select all images uploaded today, run this query:

```
$dd = ("SELECT images FROM db WHERE date_column = '2018-08-23'");
```

Replace `date_column` with your date column name.
I am assuming your date format is 'Y-m-d', replace if yours is different.

Whenever you want to select items that share the same attribute e.g name, id, date etc, simply specify the attribute name and the attribute value in your query.

So, if I want to select images that have the same title, I would simply do:

```
$dd = ("SELECT images FROM db WHERE title_column = 'Cool Images'");
```

Your own query works but you will get images that have the same `pid`.

Comment: A nice, clear and easy to read solution. To make this answer better, maybe explain what you have done and why it will now work.

Comment: @LewisBrowne Select images from database where date_column equals to the given date. The whole query is just a few English words.

Comment: @kry We both understand what it means but its for the people that may not understand it.

Comment: @LewisBrowne ... Thanks mate... I've made some edit, I hope that addresses your request.